# insert Icon in a entry (xamarin) at the begging of the text

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mobile, icons

I just want to put the icon on the begging of the Entry, there is not way, i had read and i can not, please i need any help
Here you have part of the code where i want to insert the ico

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid RowSpacing="{OnPlatform iOS=25,Android=20}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>        
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <ColumnDefinition/>
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="3" HorizontalOptions="Center"
              WidthRequest="{OnPlatform iOS=300,Android=300}"
              Orientation="Vertical">
             <!-- Here where i insert the image -->
                <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="userImage.png"></Image>
                <Label 
                    Text="Usuario"
                    FontSize="{OnPlatform Android=13}"
                    TextColor="Black"
                />
                
                <Frame 
                    HasShadow="{OnPlatform Android=true, iOS=false}"
                    Padding="{OnPlatform Android=6,iOS=0}"
                    CornerRadius="{OnPlatform Android=7}">                   

                    <Entry                              
                      
                       Placeholder="Usuario" 
                       ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing"
                       MaxLength="25"
                       FontSize="{OnPlatform Android=15,iOS=16}"                       
                       TextColor="Blue" 
                       x:Name="txtUser">                        
                    </Entry>
                </Frame>
            </StackLayout>
```

Comment: what is wrong with what you have?

Comment: The icon it is displayed at the top, i need it with the Entry at the left side.

Comment: you are using a Vertical StackLayout.  If you want the image aligned horizontally with the Entry, you need to use a Horizontal StackLayout

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using Grids and StackLayouts somewhat haphazardly.
Your problem indeed comes from trying to left align an element in a vertical StackLayout. Simply having this in an horizontal StackLayout should fix your problem.

```
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center"
                 WidthRequest="{OnPlatform iOS=300,Android=300}"
                 Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Grid.Column="1" 
               Source="userImage.png"/>
        <Label Text="Usuario"
                FontSize="{OnPlatform Android=13}"
                TextColor="Black" />
    </StackLayout>
    <Frame HasShadow="{OnPlatform Android=true, iOS=false}"
           Padding="{OnPlatform Android=6,iOS=0}"
           CornerRadius="{OnPlatform Android=7}">
        <Entry Placeholder="Usuario" 
               ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing"
               MaxLength="25"
               FontSize="{OnPlatform Android=15,iOS=16}"
               TextColor="Blue" 
               x:Name="txtUser" />
    </Frame>
</StackLayout>
```

Watch out when you are defining a "Grid.Row" or a "Grid.Column" in a xaml element that is not directly "underneath" your Grid. In your example, assigning a grid column to your image element does not work since it is a child of the StackLayout and not the Grid. This will not assign the element to any of the grid's row or column since it is not a child of it. You can look into Xamarin's [Grid Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid) documentation for more information.